# Prove that all negative integers are the limit points of $S=\{-m + \frac{1}{n} | m, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $S=\{-m + {1\over n}\}$  where $m ,n \in \mathbb N$ , and prove that $\{-1,1\}$ are the limit points.

My approach :
I understand what a limit point is - that every neighbourhood of the point contain some point of Set $S$.

if $n\to\infty$ and $m=1$ then surely $-1$ is the limit point as every neighborhood of $-1$ should contain some point of  $S$.

I am not able to prove the same for $1$ , as I can find a neighborhood $[0.5,2]$ which has no element of $S$.

Is my logic correct? also how do I develop a mathematically rigorous proof of same?

Comment: @Ludolila  thanks for editing, can you please guide me how do i edit maths equations, any link to any tutorial will do , thanks !

Comment: Are you sure the question is correct? I think every negative integer should be a limit point.

Comment: Also, this MathJaX basic tutorial explains how math markup works on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @ConnorHarris I agree every negative integer and 0 should be the limiting point right? and 1 should not be a limiting point? I do think question is ambiguous here  I found it in a text book ,  also how do I prove rigorously that any negative integer is a limiting point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $L$ of limit points of $S$ is $-\mathbb N = \{-m : m \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

> $ L \supseteq -\mathbb N $

Indeed, $x_n = -m + \frac{1}{n}$ converges to $-m$.

> $ L \subseteq -\mathbb N $

Indeed, let $a \in L$.
Note that 
$S \subseteq \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N} J_m$, where $J_m=[-m,-m+1)$ are disjoint intervals. Therefore,  there is exactly one interval $J_m$ containing $a$. But in $J_m$ the elements of $S$ form a monotone sequence converging to $-m$. Therefore, $a=-m \in -\mathbb N$.

Comment: Thanks i will edit and correct the question your solution is apt .